# Change raster values using spatial polygons

Tags: r, plot, spatial, raster, r-raster

To change raster values under `SpatialPoints` you can simply use `[` .

```
r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
rTp <- rasterToPoints(r, spatial = T)

set.seed(666)
rTpS <- rTp[sample(1:length(rTp), 500),]
plot(r)
plot(rTpS, add = TRUE, pch = ".")
```

Now, the raster values beneath the spatial points are changed like this:

```
r1 <- r
r1[rTpS] <- 99999
plot(r1)
```

**Raster with SpatialPoints (left) and raster with changed values (right):**
[image: Raster with SpatialPoints (left) and raster with changed values (right)]

Thus, I assumed that polygons work the same way. Therefore generate some polygons from this raster data set:

```
rst <- as.integer(stretch(r, 0, 10))
rTpol <- rasterToPolygons(rst, dissolve = T)
rTpol <- rTpol[rTpol$layer > 3,]

plot(r)
plot(rTpol, add = T)

rst[rTpol[,]] <- 100
plot(rst)

# also tried 
# rst[rTpol] <- 100
```

However, when i Try to change the raster values below some `SpatialPolygons`, somehow the ID (or something) of the polygons. Yet, it should be 100.

**Raster with SpatialPolygons (left) and raster with strangely changed values (right):** 
[image: Raster with SpatialPolygons (left) and raster with strangely changed values (right)]

Therefore, my question is how to change raster values within polygons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Edit (after two years):

This has been fixed as promised by Mr. Hijmans in the comments.
Thanks for this easy and awesome and convenient way of working with geo data!

## Original Answer:

Finally, I found the answer myself.

The function `rasterize()` helps with this problem.

```
r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
rst <- as.integer(stretch(r, 0, 10))
plot(rst)
rTpol <- rasterToPolygons(rst, dissolve = TRUE)
rTpol <- rTpol[rTpol$layer > 3,]
plot(rTpol)

rpol <- rasterize(rTpol, rst, field = 100, update = TRUE)
plot(rpol)
```

`rasterize()` puts the `field =` value in the rastercells generated from the polygons, while `update = TRUE` takes the raster and updates all cells wich correspond to the polygons with the field value.

The result looks like this: 
 [image]

Comment: That is a good solution, but your original solution was more elegant --- and should have worked. This bug has been fixed in (forthcoming) raster version 2.5-16

Comment: @RobertH: Do you know if the update to the raster package is already on the way?